# AOSP Build Error - error: found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead

Tags: android, android-source, android-10.0

I am trying to flash Android Q User-debug build into my Pixel2 XL device from my mac pc but its getting failed with the below error message.

```
[ 27% 31880/114806] Copy non-ELF: out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsv
FAILED: out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so
/bin/bash -c "(if prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r383902/bin/llvm-readobj -h vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvideocodec.so >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo -e \"\\033[1mout/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so: \\033[31merror:\\033[0m\\033[1m\" 'found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead.' \"\\033[0m\" >&2; echo -e \"\\033[1mout/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so: \\033[31merror:\\033[0m\\033[1m\" 'found ELF file: vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvideocodec.so' \"\\033[0m\" >&2; false; fi ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/ ) && (rm -f out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so ) && (cp \"vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvideocodec.so\" \"out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so\" )"
out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so: error: found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead. 
out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvideocodec.so: error: found ELF file: vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvideocodec.so 
[ 27% 31881/114806] Copy non-ELF: out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsv
FAILED: out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so
/bin/bash -c "(if prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-r383902/bin/llvm-readobj -h vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvtextutils.so >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo -e \"\\033[1mout/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so: \\033[31merror:\\033[0m\\033[1m\" 'found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead.' \"\\033[0m\" >&2; echo -e \"\\033[1mout/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so: \\033[31merror:\\033[0m\\033[1m\" 'found ELF file: vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvtextutils.so' \"\\033[0m\" >&2; false; fi ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/ ) && (rm -f out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so ) && (cp \"vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvtextutils.so\" \"out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so\" )"
out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so: error: found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead. 
out/target/product/taimen/system/lib/lib-imsvtextutils.so: error: found ELF file: vendor/qcom/taimen/proprietary/lib-imsvtextutils.so 
22:34:16 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Below is my build steps :

```
mkdir ~/bin
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b master
repo sync -c -j4
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/google_devices-taimen-qq1a.191205.008-f4537f93.tgz
tar xvf google_devices-taimen-qq1a.191205.008-f4537f93.tgz
./extract-google_devices-taimen.sh
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/qcom-taimen-qq1a.191205.008-760afa6e.tgz
tar xvf qcom-taimen-qq1a.191205.008-760afa6e.tgz
./extract-qcom-taimen.sh
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_taimen-userdebug
m
```

Since for the first time I am building the AOSP I couldn't understand the error `found ELF prebuilt in PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, use cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared instead.`

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

This [Issue Link](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/device/linaro/hikey/+/1309214) might be helpful for you to read.

For your issue, I believe it's related to the device binary you download.

Try to download the newest, which is listed at the bottom, for you pixel 2 XL.

Redo the extract*.sh part and make again!

Comment: While the content in the link might answer the question, please consider describing that content in this answer. The link can change at any time rendering your answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
yes, we can add this flag to BoardConfig.mk, but it is not a clean solution since Google encourages the use of Android.bp files instead of Makefiles. Thant's what the soong suggested the use of these modules (cc_prebuilt_binary / cc_prebuilt_library_shared).

In my case, solved this problem by creating Android.bp file in the repo where I put my prebuilt libraries, then I added them as product packages in the product mk file. this is an example :

Android.bp :

```
cc_prebuilt_library {
name: "product_package_name_in_MK_file",
relative_install_path: "sub_lib/sub_sub_lib",
stem: "output_file_name", // .so will be added automatically to out file name.
compile_multilib: "both",
multilib: {
lib32: {
srcs: ["path for src 32bit lib"],
},
lib64: {
srcs: ["path for src 64bit lib"],
},
},
strip: {
none:true,
},
allow_undefined_symbols: true,
check_elf_files: false,
vendor: true,
enabled: true,
}
```

product_mk file :

```
...
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += product_package_name_in_MK_file
...
```